# What are the recommended mechanism to securely distribute private keys to thousands of servers?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, facebook

I am asking this question because in this article https://engineering.fb.com/security/delegated-credentials/ there is a sentence stating "We securely distribute private keys to the servers".

I am trying to understand how that is done.

Comment: The article is about delegated credentials which is an extension to TLS. In this particular paragraph, Facebook describes what they have done to protect their certificates and keys with traditional TLS and later describes how they could improve that with delegated credentials. They did not say how they "securley distribute private keys to the servers", but i assume there is a "trusted channel" over which they send the private keys to the servers. However, this is part of how they do traditional TLS and has nothing to do with how delegated credentials work.

Comment: The article is talking about how they are innovating new ways to accomplish various things. We can't say how Facebook does it, and we can't guess, because it is innovative not standard practice.

Comment: If you are asking how it is *normally* done in a large enterprise, that's different. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, how is this part "distribute private keys to the servers" done in large enterprises? Or like jnsp says how is a "trusted channel" established. Don't you need to distribute the private keys first to establish trusted channel? Isn't that a chicken and egg situation?

Comment: In normal usage, private keys are not distributed - they are generated on the system that uses them and ideally never transferred elsewhere. The system will usually generate a certificate signing request from this key, which will then be signed by an enterprise certificate authority to verify it's authenticity. See [here](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/private-keys) for more detail.

Comment: Ok ... Then what does Facebook mean then by "we securely distribute private keys to the servers". I am confused.

Comment: You can have the certificates stored somewhere securely. When the servers start they download the certificates. I am sure there is a more secure way (see Unencoded comment)

Comment: It's just like @schroeder said, Facebook's approach is innovative and against standard practice, so there's no way of knowing what they've done unless they explain. Theoretically, any private key that is wrapped in strong encryption could be transferred using any existing way of sending data between systems and it could be described as "secure". Certificates themselves generally do not have the private key included in them - they are the public key, with associated metadata.